# dd display style changing to none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dd

I have a dl but when I run it, the dd elements work properly when dt is first clicked, but then the dd style's change to display:none, and I'm not sure why. How do I keep the style from changing? I have tried adding display: block!important to my css and to the dd tags themselves, but that didn't work. Here is my JQuery, CSS and HTML code (the JQuery is embded in `$(document).ready( function(){}`)

```
setUpMenu();

function setUpMenu() {
    $("dt").click(function(){
      $("dd").slideUp("fast");
      $(this).next().slideDown("fast");
    return false;
   });
}

<style>
dt {
    list-style: none; cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #558C89;
    width: 150px; height: 25px; 
    font-size: 1.1em; color: white;  text-align: center; 
}
dt:hover {
        background-color: #D9853B;
}
dd {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.otherMenu {
    float: left; margin-left: 3%;
}
</style>

<body>
      <div class="otherMenu">
            <label>More items available:</label>
            <dl>
                <dt>Mounts</dt>
                <dd>Picture</dd>
                <dd>Photos</dd>
                <dt>Shadow Boxes</dt>
                <dt>Multi-frames +</dt>
                <dd>2 picture</dd>
                <dd>3 picture </dd>
                <dd>4 picture</dd>
                <dt>Posters frames</dt>
                <dt>Artist frames</dt>
                <dt>Classic posters</dt>
                <dt>Accessories</dt>
            </dl>
        </div>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this line : `$("dd").slideUp("fast");`

It means that when `dd` are visible, they turns to hide because of the `slideUp()` function. The contrary is `slideDown()` which show them.

**EDIT**

If I understand correctly what you're asking you can use `nextUntil()` function to open all `dd` elements until the next `dt` element

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/27dz367z/)

```
setUpMenu();

function setUpMenu() {
    $("dt").click(function(){
      $("dd").slideUp("fast");
      $(this).nextUntil("dt", "dd" ).slideDown("fast");
    return false;
   });
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but this resulted in the dt elements not closing up when clicked, which is what I want too, like an accordion menu.